What does "EA TRAX" do?
In the Audio settings of Need for Speed: Carbon for PS3, what does the "EA TRAX" option do?


EA Trax is a branding used by Electronic Arts for the soundtracks in their EA and EA Sports video games. They often feature prominent artists with the tracks reflecting the culture associated with a particular game. They will also often feature exclusive tracks recorded specifically for a game or a version of a popular song with new lyrics that match the theme of the game.
A game that uses EA Trax has songs from various genres that depend on the game, a mixed soundtrack genre for Need for Speed games.
The game soundtrack plays depending on the class of the car the player is driving.
Source Fandom, see here and here.

What plays if EA Trax is disabled? Does it use unmodified versions of the songs?

More likely totally different songs
